# where do xrp ledger gateways get their xrp from?

Tags: ripple, xrp

im learning xrpl, but im confused about how to get xrp into a private exchange?

https://xrpl.org/become-an-xrp-ledger-gateway.html

"A Private Exchange holds XRP and lets its customers buy and sell that XRP in its own system. Most cryptocurrencies rely on private exchanges to provide a market for the cryptocurrency, but the XRP Ledger has a currency exchange built into the protocol itself."

where does that xrp come from?

Answer (score 0):

The link you've posted is for exchanges and not for end users. Exchanges get XRP from users. Users transfer XRP to the exchange and trade it there! So the exchange just have to setup the wallet and users can start depositing and withdrawing XRP from exchanges!
(If the exchange is responsible enough, they'll even setup their own node and actively maintain it.)

Your question is not very clear to me. If you can rephrase your question I'll try my best to help you.

If you want to learn more about XRPL you can check this: [Xumm Developer Education](https://learn.xumm.dev/).

Comment: Yes im trying to figure out where do private xrp exchanges get their xrp? if i go to binance or xumm and buy xrp where did the xrp come from? where do exchanges get their xrp to sell to its users? ... from other users? well then where did they get it from? i want to be my own exchange... hence the link, becoming a gateway

Comment: Most crypto companies do something like ICO or IEO and sell their generated tokens to retail users. This gets them their initial money to continue working on their project.

Some projects also give their tokens to some charities: that way, these charities sell on exchange and get money from users who bought those tokens. Some do free airdrops - that way the project gets exposure(marketing).

You can know more about XRP here: https://xrpl.org/history.html
While you are at the above page, don't forget to click on "Read more" links to get full details. It's an interesting read nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get an idea how ripple works. [XRP Labs](https://xrpl.org) are the foundation responsible for development of XRP and it is not for profit. They provided a fixed supply (100B XRP), almost have of that is in [circulation](https://capital.com/ripple-who-owns-most-xrp) currently. There is no mining or stacking in XRP.

On the other hand, [Ripple](https://ripple.com) is a for profit company and the provide a [liquidity solutions](https://ripple.com/solutions/crypto-liquidity/) for businesses. So, you need to seek a partnership with them. Other options would be signing up for one of XRP exchanges like [Gatehub](https://gatehub.net/) or [Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/). Also, the great thing about Ripple network, is that it a decentralized exchange by default. So, once you have a liquidity (of any available currency), you trade with a decentralized exchange like [sologenic](https://sologenic.org/).